# Datetime as a dimension in python KDTree

Tags: python, time, numpy, spatial, kdtree

Currently have a working example using `scipy.spatial.KDTree` to do a nearest neighbour look up for some x,y points.

Question is, if I have datetime data for each x,y point can I put that into a KDTree and modify my spatial nearest neighbour search to do a nearest spatio-temporal neighbour search?

Searching for nearest spatial neighbours with:

> `pts = np.array([[1, 50], [1.89, 52.4]])`
>
> `print tree.query(pts, k=5)`

Comment: I think this thread can help answer your question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/788005/is-a-kd-tree-suitable-for-4d-space-time-data-x-y-z-time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/788005/is-a-kd-tree-suitable-for-4d-space-time-data-x-y-z-time) Also what about just using the datetime property to filter your point before building the tree?

Comment: Thanks for that, its clarified a few things. Could you expand on your last line please? Suppose you want to return points in a SPATIAL distance and within a TIME period. Would a KD-Tree be able to do this? Using 'KDTree.query' you can say give me the closest n points, but what if you want to specify that time range too? The spatial search can be done by 'KDTree.query_ball_point' or similar.