# Efficiently find closest points to track in space & time on gridded data

Tags: python, latitude-longitude, nearest-neighbor, kdtree

**Summary/simplified version**

Given a list of track points defined by three 1-dimensional arrays (`lats`, `lons` and `dtime` all with same length) and a gridded 3-dimensional array `rr` (defined by 2-D `lat_radar`, `lon_radar` coordinate arrays and a 1-dimensional time array `time_radar`) I want to extract all the grid values in `rr` where the coordinates (latitude, longitude AND time included) are closest to the three 1-dimensional arrays.

I've managed to use `cKDTree` to select points in space but I don't know how to generalize the solution to space & time together. Right now I have to do the selection on time separately and it makes the code quite bulky and hard to read.

for more details about this problem see hereinafter

---

**Extended version**

I'm trying to develop an app that uses precipitation data obtained from weather radar composites to predict the precipitation along a track. Most apps usually predict the precipitation at a point without considering the point moving in time.

The idea is, given points identifying a track in space and time, find the closest grid points from radar data to obtain a precipitation estimate over the track (see plot). The final goal would be to shift the start time to identify the best time to leave to avoid rain.

[image]

I just optimized my previous algorithm, that was using plain loops, to use `cKDTree` from `scipy`. Execution time went down from 30s to 380ms :). However I think the code can still be optimized. Here is my attempt.

As input we have

- `lons`, `lats`: coordinates of the track as N-dimensional arrays
- `dtime`: `timedelta` T-dimensional array containing the time elapsed on the track
- `lon_radar`, `lat_radar`: M x P matrices containing the coordinates of the radar data
- `dtime_radar`: `timedelta` Q-dimensional array containing the radar forecast
- `rr`: M x P X Q array containing the radar forecast at every time step

First find the grid points closest to the trajectory using `cKDTree`:

```py
combined_x_y_arrays = np.dstack([lon_radar.ravel(), 
                                 lat_radar.ravel()])[0]
points_list = list(np.vstack([lons, lats]).T)

def do_kdtree(combined_x_y_arrays, points):
    mytree = cKDTree(combined_x_y_arrays)
    dist, indexes = mytree.query(points)
    return indexes

results = do_kdtree(combined_x_y_arrays, points_list)
# As we have many duplicates, since the itinerary has a much higher resolution than the radar,
# we only select the unique points 
inds_itinerary = np.unique(results)
lon_lat_itinerary = combined_x_y_arrays[inds_itinerary]
```

then find the closest points in the track to subset it. It doesn't make sense to have a track resolution of 10 m if the radar only has grid points every km.

```py
combined_x_y_arrays = np.vstack([lons, lats]).T
points_list = list(lon_lat_itinerary)

results = do_kdtree(combined_x_y_arrays, points_list)
```

Now we can use these positions to get the elapsed time on the trajectory and the relative time steps in radar data

```py
dtime_itinerary = dtime[results]
# find indices of these dtimes in radar dtime 
inds_dtime_radar = np.abs(np.subtract.outer(dtime_radar, dtime_itinerary)).argmin(0)
```

Now we have everything that we need to find the precipitation so we only need one last loop. I also loop on `shifts` to obtain prediction with different start times.

```py
shifts = (1, 3, 5, 7, 9)

rain = np.empty(shape=(len(shifts), len(inds_itinerary)))
for i, shift in enumerate(shifts):
    temp = []
    for i_time, i_space in zip(inds_dtime_radar, inds_itinerary):
        temp.append(rr[i_time+shift].ravel()[i_space])
    rain[i, :] = temp
```

In particular I would like to find a way to combine the time search with the lat-lon search for the closest points.

Comment: Could you rephrase your question to be more precise and specific?

Comment: More specific than this? :) I posted a picture and the full working code snippet... Honestly I think already now the question is too long and with too many details. Which parts should I elaborate more?

Comment: What I mean is, quite the opposite. Your question is lost in too many details. Can you rephrase it to ask a specific question instead?

Comment: Makes sense. I've added a summarized version of the question at the top. I'm not confident in deleting also the detailed part so I will leave it there for now :)

Comment: I think I found out why this is so complicated...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18135476/datetime-as-a-dimension-in-python-kdtree, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788005/is-a-kd-tree-suitable-for-4d-space-time-data-x-y-z-time. So probably my question is related to these